# Place button above list container, right justified

Tags: css

I am trying to get a button to appear above an unordered list, and I want it right justified.  With CSS style "float:right", it appears on the right, but it is overlapping the list.  How can I get the button to appear on the right without overlapping the list?

Code:

```
<style>
.mylist { list-style-type: none; width: 100%; }
.mylist li { margin: 2px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid black;}
</style>

<button style="float:right; display:block;">Preview</button>
<UL class='mylist'>
    <LI>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</LI>
    <LI>Test</LI>       
</UL>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **clear:both** to **mylist** style.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JgeTm/

**CSS**

```
.mylist{list-style-type:none;width:100%;clear:both}
```

Comment: Actually, this is not working in Firefox.  (Works in Chrome though.)

Comment: Must work in almost all (to not say all) browsers. IE, FF, CR, OP, SA... Both CSS properties, are **version:CSS1** // If is not working for you, probably something change, uncomplete or not well defined. Give us the full code if you want, to take a look.